# Start date and end date based on employee available leaves

Tags: jquery

I have requirement where an employee applys for leaves specifing Start_date and End_date.

Requirements:

1. Start_date would be starting from today and future dates.
2. End_date will be starting based on Start_date.
3. Every employee has some available leaves, where he/she can maximum apply for.
   for example: if start_date is from 20/10/2014 and employee has 4 available leaves, then End_date must start from 20/10/2014 and maximum enable days will be 4 i.e 20,21,22,23 he can apply leaves.

I have tried to achive this functionality by below code, but its not working in some of the cases fine.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<script>// Start Date
$(function() {
    var dateToday = new Date(); 
    $( "#Sdate" ).datepicker({
        minDate: dateToday
    });
});

</script>

<script> // End Date
$(function() {
    var available_leaves = 4;
    var startdate=$('#Sdate').val();
    console.log("Start Date->" + startdate);

    $( "#Edate" ).datepicker({
        'minDate':startdate,
        'maxDate':available_leaves
    });
});

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Start Date: <input type="text" id="Sdate"></p>

<p> End Date: <input type="text" id="Edate"></p>
```

Comment: If it works for some cases, how do we know what cases don't work?

Comment: Just a thought regarding the requirements... If you keep the restriction of leave application from start date of today or future, you may have trouble applying leaves that were taken in past... if people fall sick or any other emergency happens and they can't apply for the leave beforehand, how will the system handle it?